# Laravel Job Not being attempted

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

Laravel is not being attempted (attempts = 0). I have created jobs table and dispatched a job.

The job is now currently being listed in the `jobs` table but with attempts = 0

I have updated `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` and run `php artisan config:cache`. I have also hit `queue:restart` but still same result.

Additionally, I have tried with `php artisan queue:work --force` (without force as well) and `php artisan queue:listen` as well but still not being attempted.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you try specifying the queue name ? Something like `php artisan queue:work --queue=myQueue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have dispatched the job to the **property** queue. To process this queue run:

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=property
```

Comment: I got it. Your answer work. However, what if I need to run every property type

Comment: You don't have to specify a different queue for each job. Laravel will use the default queue. Like this `ProcessProperty::dispatch($property);`. The command to run would just be `php artisan queue:work` to process all jobs on the default queue.